# Google Maps API v3 custom animations on marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I wonder if it's possible to change Google Maps' default marker graphic to a custom animated sequence (.gif or .swf) to achieve the same effect as Apple Maps does when showing current location via GPS:

[image]

Probably it can be done with javascript & custom overlays, but I think it won't be as smooth as Apple Maps animation. (damn js!)

Comment: you may use custom icons for markers, animated GIF's are possible too.

Answer (score 1):

As a standard, the markers use something called optimized rendering that always renders the markers as static. To see animated gifs you need to set optimized = false on your marker. The code for generating your marker would then be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    icon: youricon,
    optimized: false
  });
```

And for icon similar to the one of apple Maps, you will need to have a similar gif icon.
This should solve your problem.